# Create a macro to find a value in Column B and if any matching case then copy the corresponding cell value

Tags: excel, vba

```
ReporteeID  Manager ID
R1001   M1001
R1002   M1002
R1003   M1003
R1004   M1001
R1005   M1002
R1006   M1003
R1007   M1001
R1008   M1002
R1009   M1003
R1010   M1001
```

Out Put Should be Like below

```
M1001   R1001   R1004   R1007   R1010
M1002   R1002   R1005   R1008   
M1003   R1003   R1009
```

My request is to create a macro which could FIND the ManagerID (column) loop through all the cells and wherever it matches the left side column (ReporteeID) cell value should be copy and paste in another sheet to the corresponding ManagerID(M1001) rows through xltoright right side

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  As many new members misunderstand Stack Overflow is not a code for me site, but a site to help overcome specific problems with existing code.  That being said, this particular problem has been answered many times and a targeted search on google may find those.  If you have existing code please post it in your original post and we will help figure out why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a start:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim N2 As Long, i As Long, K As Long
    Dim v As String, N1 As Long

    Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    sh1.Range("B:B").Copy sh2.Range("A1")
    sh2.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    N2 = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    N1 = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To N2
        K = 2
        v = sh2.Cells(i, 1).Value
        For j = 2 To N1
            If v = sh1.Cells(j, 2).Value Then
                sh2.Cells(i, K).Value = sh1.Cells(j, 1).Value
                K = K + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You really great. Your the master of Excel and I am part of this to learning on your shadow. Thanks for your assistance. The coding give the exact output for me.